# unused args [...] for include of [...]

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to pass an argument to a launch file, and I keep getting this error.

The main launch file has something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <include file="$(find p2os_urdf)/launch/upload_pioneer3at.xml">
        <arg name="foo" value="bar"/>
    </include>
 ...
</launch>
```

The included file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <param name="testing" value="$(arg foo)"/>
</launch>
```

Yet I keep getting this error:

```
unused args [foo] for include of [/home/sciencectn/builds/ros/src/p2os_urdf/launch/upload_pioneer3at.xml]
```

I assume it means the "foo" argument was never used when it clearly is. What's going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239384/unused-args-%5B...%5D-for-include-of-%5B...%5D/) by [sciencectn](https://answers.ros.org/users/27472/sciencectn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch is very strict about argument passing; you can't use an argument (`$(arg foo)`) without first declaring that the launch file takes an argument (`<arg name="foo"/>`).

in addition, passing arguments that are not expected, or failing to pass arguments that do not have a default is an error. (very similar to passing arguments when calling a function in C++ or python)

Therefore, your included launch file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <arg name="foo"/> <!-- declare that this launch file requires an argument -->

    <param name="testing" value="$(arg foo)"/> <!-- use the argument -->
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2